# \mkbibquote used referencing title of a paper is "paper". How about 'paper'?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

How to make the title of the paper from:

```
NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies : towards Attali's "Composition"
```

to

```
NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies : towards Attali's 'Composition'
```

I am using:

```
  title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's \mkbibquote{Composition}},
```

[image]

My MWE:

```
% \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % macros to modify appearance of 'itemize' environments

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
% style=authoryear, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
% citestyle=authoryear, 
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits,
uniquename=init]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %for second and third author name

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\space} %to delete . after (1997)

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} %for conference title delete ".."
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for incollecion title italic ONLY
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for phdthesis title italic ONLY



\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}



\newcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\volnumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\newcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\jourserdelim}{\newunitpunct}
\newcommand*{\servoldelim}{\jourvoldelim}
\newcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\volnumdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}  
% to make volume (number), eg. 4(2)



% for delete comma after Author A and Aurhor b
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
   \let\finalandcomma\empty
   \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
 }

\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{given-family}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}}     


\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}



% \usepackage{parskip}  

\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}




\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}


@article{dean2005noisespeech,
  title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's \mkbibquote{Composition}},
  author={Dean, Roger T},
  journal={NMEDIAC: Journal of New Media \& Culture},
  year={2005},
  number={1},
  volume={3}
}


\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


 in \textcite{dean2005noisespeech} 


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This depends on your `babel` language settings. What language are you using? American English uses double quotes (by default). British and Australian English uses single quotes. You can load the `csquotes` package and specify what style you want for outer and inner quote marks too.

Comment: Oh! I see you are just using `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. You could specify `\usepackage[british]{babel}` and you will get single quotes everywhere at the outer level. But this may not be what you want and will also affect other things like date format.

Comment: @DavidPurton. Thanks. If did not use `\usepackage[british]{babel}`. How can do a `csquotes`. In my MWE above, I do not have this `\usepackage[british]{babel}`

Comment: You could replace `\usepackage{csquotes}` with `\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}`.

Comment: @DavidPurton thanks. I had added in `\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}`. However, overleaf said `LaTexError: Option clash for packae csquotes` and  `please see your \documentclass declaration may fix this.` I check mine, i am using `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}`.

Comment: You already load `\usepackage{csquotes}`. You're loading it twice now. Remove `\usepackage{csquotes}`.

Comment: @DavidPurton, Yes, I did that. I only have `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}` and `\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}`. It said: `LaTexError: Option clash for packae csquotes` and `please see your \documentclass declaration may fix this.`

Comment: The fact that you get the option clash means that you *are* loading it more than once with different options. Look for `csquotes` elsewhere in your code or included files. I do not get this error in your MWE and it successfully gives me only single quotes.

Comment: @DavidPurton, thanks. Is my mistake, it worked. Secondly, I am not sure is answer `will create an issue of the letter` =  `J` in my reference as I asked in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510018/why-my-j-appear-in-referencing-is-different-from-appear-in-the-normal-j-chap

Comment: @DavidPurton Do you want to write up an answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can do this:

You can change your language to `british` (or `australian`) which uses single quotation marks for outer marks. i.e.,

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

Bear in mind that this will also change other language related things like date formats.

The other option is to specify the quotation style directly with `csquotes`. i.e.,

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

This will use British style single quotation marks for outer quotation marks, but keep other language settings to `babel`'s default for `english` (basically American English).

Comment: thanks. Can I know is this related to all `punctuation`, like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510630/is-using-addendum-for-accessed-date-for-citing-a-website-in-biblatex

Comment: @aan, I'll answer that in a moment.

Comment: Do you have time to look at `citing secondary source` in this question link here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516877/how-to-cite-secondary-source-textciteprimarysource-parencitecited-insec