# How do I write an indirect citation in APA style using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa7

How do I create an APA 7 indirect citation in LaTeX using the `biblatex` citation package? Output should look like this:

> (Hørland, 2014, as cited in Chiu & Lu, 2016, p. 1)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the short compilable TeX code you have tried so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing. please do not forget and add the used bib entry to your question!

Comment: Are you loading the `biblatex` package with the option `style=apa`?

Comment: @Mico yes, here is the full package: \usepackage[
 style=authoryear-comp,
 dashed=false,
 citestyle=apa,
 backend=biber,
 refsegment=chapter,
 sorting=nyt,
 defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

Comment: I think the question is about whether it's possible to add second citation as a postnote (which it's not), so this has to be done manually, AFAICT.

Comment: Unrelated, but it's generally not a good idea to mix the `apa` citation style with a different bibliography style. It might have unexpected effects.

Comment: @AlanMunn Noted! I'm already keeping an eye out but this was the only way I could figure out including the APA 7 style as the "style=apa" created an error message. I'm still new to latex

Comment: @karo.anton Hmm. `style=apa` should be all you need (as my example shows), and that will give you conforming APA7 styles.  When you change styles it's always a good idea to remove auxiliary files from previous runs before recompiling. Perhaps that was the source of your error.

Comment: @AlanMunn I went back and changed it after seeing your comment and it worked out this time! Not sure what has going on during the previous attempts but that's a moot point now. So now you've helped me twice over - Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested citations aren't possible in `biblatex`, but there are commands to string together multiple citations and this can be used to achieve what you want.  Since the default delimiter between citations in parentheses is `;`, but in this use case you need `,` we temporarily redefine the multicite delimiter (surrounded by `{...}` to limit its scope) before using the `\parencites` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
{\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}\parencites{knuth:ct:a}[as cited in][p.1]{companion}}

\parencite{knuth:ct:a,companion}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is a more comprehensive answer, which also includes a version of indirect `\textcite`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516901/46356.